# Visual Studio code wrongly recognizes point.c file as a C++ source file

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

When I create file named `points.c` VS code wrongly recognizes it as a C++ file.
[image: Fig-1]

Within this file, intellisense suggestions are based on C++ and not C.

[image: Fig-2]

However, files with other file names like `hello.c` or `point.c` are recognized properly as C source code.

Comment: `c` is a valid extension for a C++ file.  Is it possible Intellisense is scanning the file and you have some C++ code in it?

Comment: This is unusual to me. So the content of the file is empty outside of the `#include <`

Comment: Yes, the file has only one line `#include <`. Even when the file is empty, it is associated with c++ icon in VS code file explorer.  Also, I could not replicate this issue in a different directories.

Comment: There are some issues with intellisense, I've seen that happen, another thing I've seen is sometimes when you change the type of a variable it takes some time for it to realize that change, report it as a bug https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be filed as bugticket. There is no actual programming involved.

Comment: Is this file compiled as C++ or C?

Comment: No, I did not compile this file yet.

Comment: I found `"points.C": "cpp"` in  `settings.json` file in the parent directory. Though, I am not sure how this happened.